# Why do 'htop' and 'top' show different memory usage?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management

In order to diagnosis memory of computer, I've checked the memory usage by using `htop` and `top`.

At that time, I've found that the memory usage reported from `htop` and `top` are different.

I haven't run so much programs, but `top` reported that I'm using more that one third of the memory while `htop` says I use only small memory.

I cannot understand this difference. Why they reported different result? I wish my the computer does not have any problem :(

First result is from `htop` and the next is from `top`.

[image]

Comment: `top` counts vfs cache as used, while `htop` does not. See [LinuxAteMyRam.com](https://www.linuxatemyram.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Top counts the cache aswell.

So if you do:

X = Used

Y = Buffers

Z = Cached

X - Y - Z = HTOPMEM